# Router: CanActivate on top level route

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

Before loading the app I want to check if the user is signed in and load some data. Therefore I put two guards on the top route, but they don't get executed. Isn't it possible to put canActivate on the top level route? Are there any limitation on where to put the guards?

**Route Config**

```
export const routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        canActivate: [IsAuthenticatedGuard, IsDataLoadedGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: '/something',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

*/something is part of a different module, the route gets loaded in the other module using RouterModule.forChild()*

**Guards**

```
@Injectable()
export class IsAuthenticatedGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private _router: Router) {}

    canActivate(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot
    ): Observable<boolean> {
        if (!this._isSignedIn()) {
            window.location.replace('/signin.html');
            return Observable.of(false);
        }
        return Observable.of(true);
    }

    _isSignedIn(): boolean {
        return document.cookie.indexOf('jwt_cookie') !== -1;
    }
}


@Injectable()
export class IsDataLoadedGuard implements CanActivate {

    private homeState$: Observable<IHomeState>;

    constructor(private _router: Router, private _store: Store<IAppState>) {
        this.homeState$ = _store.select('home');
    }

    canActivate(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot
    ): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.homeState$.map((homeState: IHomeState) =>
            !homeState.get('loading') || homeState.hasIn(['home', 'id'])
        );
    }
}
```

The app does get redirected to `/something`, when it actually should redirect to `/signin.html`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need canActivateChild on the parent route. See the docs [here](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/index/CanActivateChild-interface.html). Useful if you want a protected sub route. You can use the your same class IsAuthenticatedGuard for it.

Comment: I tried, but this didn't work either, I will try it again and report back the observed behavior.